# Python - finding next and previous values in list with different criteria

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm looking for a way to iterate through a list of numbers in Python to find the index of a particular element and then find the nearest elements to it that meet certain criteria. I can't seem to find any built in functions that will hold my place in a list so that I can find previous and next items with different search criteria. Does anything like this exist in Python?

I have a long list of numbers in which I'm trying to find a particular recurring pattern.

For example:

```
L = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 9, 1, 1, 1]
```

Say I want to find the peaks by looking for the index of the first number in the list >4, and then the indices of the nearest numbers <2 on either side. Then I want to find the next peak and do the same thing. (The actual pattern is more complicated than this.)

So the eventual output I'm looking for in this example is 1:6, 10:13.

I'm using this to find the first value:

```
a = next(i for i, v in enumerate(L) if v > 4)
```

Or this to find all values > 4 to later group them:

```
indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(L) if v > 4]
```

I've tried next, iter, generators, many kinds of for loops and more without success. I've looked at islice also, but it seems like overkill to slice the list in two for every index found and then do forward and reverse searches on the two pieces. There must be a less convoluted way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to your description, after first round, output should be [5, 1] and indexes should be [3, 6], isn't it? I don't understand where 1:6 comes from. Could you please explain that?

Comment: @m170897017: the first > 4 occurs at index 3, but the OP wants where the indices just before and after that index (> 4) which are < 2. Hence, for the first example, that's correctly: indices 1 and 6, respectively.

Comment: Using a doubly linked list might make this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a  generator function and track the indices matching your conditions as you iterate over the input:

```
L = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 9, 1, 1, 1]

def peak_groups(l):
    start_i = 0
    peak_i = None
    for i,x in enumerate(l):
        if peak_i is None:
            # look for start of peak group, or peak itself
            if x < 2:
                start_i = i
            elif x > 6:
                peak_i = i
        else:
            # look for end of peak group
            if x < 2:
                yield (start_i, peak_i, i)
                start_i = i
                peak_i = None

    # finally check edge condition if we reached the end of the list
    if peak_i is not None:
        yield (start_i, peak_i, i)

for group in peak_groups(L):
    print group
```

Results in:

```
(1, 4, 6)
(10, 11, 13)
```

The nice thing is you're only iterating over the input once. Though it might not be so simple with your real world grouping conditions.

You'll have to think about what should happen if multiple "peak groups" overlap, and this currently doesn't find the greatest peak in the group, but it should be a starting point.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I don't need to worry about overlapping groups or largest peaks, only the region each motif occurs in, so this works perfectly without too much modification.

Answer (score 2):

This finds the peaks as you stated, but requires the initial index of the list to determine where to search:

```
def findpeaks(lst, index, v1, v2):
    l = lst[index:]
    ele = next(i for (i, v) in enumerate(l) if v > v1)
    idx = ele - next(i for (i, v) in enumerate(l[:ele+1][::-1]) if v < v2)
    jdx = ele + next(i for (i, v) in enumerate(l[ele:]) if v < v2)
    # Returns a tuple containing:
    #
    # the index of the element > v1
    # the index of the element < v2 (found before the element > v1),
    # the index of the element < v2 (found after the element > v1).
    return (ele + index, idx + index, jdx + index)
```

This works by:

1. Finding the element matching the first value's criterion (> 4, in your example)
2. Finding the element before this index that matches that criterion of the second value (< 2). It does this by creating a slice of the list from where it finds the index from part 1, and reversing it. The index you find then has to be subtracted from where the index of part 1 is.
3. Search forward by creating a slice of the original list, and looking from there.
4. The end result has to take into account the starting index, so add that to the results. And, that's it.

For example:

```
L = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 9, 1, 1, 1]

print findpeaks(L, 0, 4, 2) # prints (3, 1, 6)
print findpeaks(L, 6, 4, 2) # prints (11, 10, 13)
```

The next obvious step is to find all the elements that meet this criterion. One suggestion would be to make this recursive - but you can do that on your own.

Comment: I went ahead with the other solution, but this also works, thank you.